# Parsing a dictionary of strings that refer to each other into SymPy expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I have a python dictionary like this:

```
A = {'a':'x**2', 'b':'a*x', 'c':'b'}
```

Here `x` is a `sympy` variable. Now I want to get the derivatives like this:

```
da/dx = 2*x, db/dx = 3*x**2, dc/dx = 3*x**2
```

So `a`, `b` and `c` has to be considered as the LHS of three different expressions and `x` is the only `sympy` variable.

I tried using `sympify`, but that only converts RHS from a string to expression. For the differentiation I want to use `sy.diff`. How can I do this?

Comment: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html should help.!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky dictionary, which has to be read several times to find out what means what. So I'll use a "repeated subs" helper:

```
def repeated_subs(expr, dict):
    while True:
        new_expr = expr.subs(dict)
        if new_expr == expr:
            return expr
        else:
            expr = new_expr
```

Now the rest is easy:

```
x = symbols('x')    
B = {S(key): S(A[key], locals={'x': x}) for key in A}   # S is short for sympify
for key in B:
    pprint(Eq(Derivative(key, x), repeated_subs(key, B).diff(x)))
```

This prints

```
d          
──(a) = 2⋅x
dx         
d          2
──(b) = 3⋅x 
dx          
d          2
──(c) = 3⋅x 
dx
```

The part `locals={'x': x}` is optional here, but in general it is needed to make sure that the string character "x" gets mapped to the symbol `x` that was already created, instead of something new.